# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds in django

Tags: python, django

views.py file

```
def rpa_save(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    test_kodu = request.POST.get('test_kodu')
    test_kodu = str(test_kodu)
    OlcumSonucLOG, dfLimit, urun_kodu = Providers.getir(test_kodu=test_kodu,is_emri=is_emri)
```

my providers.py file

```
@staticmethod
    def getir(test_kodu,is_emri):

        _, cur = Connection.connect_to_btr()

    sfTestler = RawDataProvider.get_sftestler_db(cur, is_emri) 
   
    firstOrder = min(sfTestler['ORDERNO'].values,default=None)
    lastOrder = max(sfTestler['ORDERNO'].values,default=None)
    
    
    df = RawDataProvider.get_pklsonuclar_db(cur, firstOrder, lastOrder)
    dfSpecific = df[df['TESTKODU']==str(test_kodu)]
    dfSpecific.loc[:, ["BATCHNO", "TESTNO"]] = dfSpecific.loc[:, ["BATCHNO", "TESTNO"]].astype('int')
    dfSpecific = dfSpecific.sort_values(['BATCHNO', 'TESTNO'], ascending=[True, True])
    urun_kodu = dfSpecific['URUNKODU'].iloc[0].split("-")[0]
```

when i try send test_kodu and is_emri variables to providers.py i get single positional indexer is out-of-bounds from this line `urun_kodu = dfSpecific['URUNKODU'].iloc[0].split("-")[0]` how can i fix it ?